# How to know which third party affects my app size?

Tags: ios

I want to understand which of the third libraries I'm using affect my app size the most (Mixpanel, Crashlytics, etc...).
How can I do that?

Comment: are you manually adds libraries or using pods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a .app file in project and file show in finder.

[image]

Show package contents of .app

[image]

In package Contents you get information about framework, icon and file size.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your 3rd-party library are all dynamic ones, it's in folder of the bundle as Harshal Valanda shows.

If you have some static libraries linked, it may be hard for you to find which one contributes the most in your final binary.

Comment:           user3349433 @user3349433